# app getting crashed while creating the managedObjectModel of Coredata

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, xcode4.2, core-data-migration

I am creating a managedObjectModel object from the following code

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {

if (managedObjectModel_ != nil) {
    return managedObjectModel_;
}
NSString *modelPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DataHouse" ofType:@"momd"];

NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:modelPath];
managedObjectModel_ = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

return managedObjectModel_;
```

}

i have **DataHouse.xcdatamodeld** file in my xcode project. This code is working absolutely fine. Now, coming to the problem.... I have made a **frawework out of my code** by following [this wonderful link](http://db-in.com/blog/2011/07/universal-framework-iphone-ios-2-0/#list_contents). i have included my framework in a new project and tried running it. The app crashed on me exactly in the above code base. I know the reason for it too but unable to resolve it. The problem here is that while creating the managedObjectModel, the compiler is looking for the file called DataHouse.xcdatamodeld in the **Main bundle**. but this file is a part of the new framrwork and is not present in the main bundle. Now, how am i supposed to solve this problem.. Any ideas please...

Answer (score 0):

There are several other class methods on `NSBundle` to load a bundle instead of `mainBundle`. With them, you should be able to specify the correct bundle location.

Have a look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: yes dude.. but the problem is that in the main project the datamodeld class will be a part of main bundle. But, in cae of framework it no longer belongs to main bundle... i got struck at this point... Any help with this???