# how to access a file which is a not a part of main bundle in iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode4.2, nsurl, nsbundle

i have a file in the main bundle which i am accessing by using the following code base.

```
   NSString *modelPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DataHouse" ofType:@"momd"];
   NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:modelPath];
   managedObjectModel_ = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
```

But i have a [special requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724974/app-getting-crashed-while-creating-the-managedobjectmodel-of-coredata) where in the above mentioned **Core data datamodel file**  will not be a part of the main bundle and will become a part of a **custom made framework**. Is there anyway in which i can access that file without referring it from the Bundle... 
In other words, how can i access the core data file without giving the path name.

Answer (score 4):

It will then become part of another custom bundle ; you'll get its path like this :

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Custom.bundle/Images/exemple.png"]
```

Comment: thanks for the tip dude... but, like i said the datamodel is a part of a framework and we dont have the exact path for that file

Comment: i have nothing... all i know is that it is a part of a framework... :(